# Remove line breaks from <code>?

Tags: code

This code form HTML editor:

```
<code>&#91;shortcode&#93;
    &#91;bar&#93;foo&#91;/bar&#93;
    &#91;bar&#93;foo&#91;/bar&#93;
    &#91;bar&#93;foo&#91;/bar&#93;
&#91;/shortcode&#93;</code>
```

Returns:

```
[shortcode]<br />
   [bar]foo[/bar]<br />
   [bar]foo[/bar]<br />
   [bar]foo[/bar]<br />
[/shortcode]
```

Codes white-space is set to pre-wrap in css (and I want it this way) and I'm using this piece of code (works for shortcodes, usually):

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99 );`enter code here`
```

I don't want to use plugins or delete these line breaks using JavaScript. Any ideas? I can't edit WP core files too (only theme's). I know it's doable because I've seen many premium themes with pretty & clean code sections.

[edit]

Using `<code><pre>contents</pre></code>` somehow deletes all the `<br/>` tags from code (why?), but I don't want to add `<pre>` every time I write some code.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking? Your question takes the form "I have X and I have Y, I'm doing Z" but nowhere have you actually asked a question...

Comment: I just want to avoid Wordpress doing ANYTHING to my code tags, including adding any html tags and reformatting white space :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress assumes that you use `<code>` for inline code and `<pre>` for a box of code. In your case, then, you shouldn't have any need to use `<pre><code>` but just `<pre>`

**See: [Writing Code in Your Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts)**